# Can't get data with php from db2 created global temporal table created by stored procedure in one transaction

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo, transactions, db2

I've got remote DB2 on z/OS and permissions ONLY for stored procedures (and created global temporary tables created by them, if *SELECT* from other tables - got permission error).

DB2 Administrator says that I've got no data output, because I'm commiting transaction after calling store procedure and created global temporal table clears after that immediatly. But in code I've got *beginTransaction* and *commit* only after selecting from created global temporal table. Trying to get data with this code:

```
try {
    $conPDO = new PDO("ibm:DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=DB;HOSTNAME=192.168.10.10;PORT=446;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;", "log", "pass"
        , [
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL,
            PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT => FALSE,
        ]
    );
    $conPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, 0);

    $transactionOn = $conPDO->beginTransaction();
    echo "<pre>";
    echo("Begin of Transaction: ");
    var_dump($transactionOn);
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "<pre>";
    echo("PDO::inTransaction: ");
    var_dump($conPDO->inTransaction());
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($conPDO);
    echo "</pre>";
    $sql = "CALL SOME.PROCEDURE (3,'2017-05-01',0,0,0,?,?,?);";
    $stmt = $conPDO->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $errorNumber, PDO::PARAM_INT | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $errorCode, PDO::PARAM_INT | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $errorMC, PDO::PARAM_STR | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT);
    $exec = $stmt->execute();
    echo "<pre>";
    echo("SQL: ");
    var_dump($sql);
    echo("Result of CALL execution: ");
    var_dump($exec);
    echo "</pre>";

    $sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM SOME.TMP_TABLE;";
    $stmt = $conPDO->prepare($sqlSelect);
    $exec = $stmt->execute();
    echo "<pre>";
    echo("SQL: ");
    var_dump($sqlSelect);
    echo("Result of SELECT execution: ");
    var_dump($exec);
    echo "</pre>";

    echo "<pre>";
    echo("Result of fetchAll from SELECT: ");
    var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    echo "</pre>";

    $stmt->closeCursor();
    $stmt = null;
    $commit = $conPDO->commit();

    echo "<pre>";
    echo("Result of Commit: ");
    var_dump($commit);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<pre>";
    echo("PDO::inTransaction: ");
    var_dump($conPDO->inTransaction());
    echo "</pre>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo($e->getMessage());
}
```

In output i've got:

> Begin of Transaction: bool(true)
>
> PDO::inTransaction: bool(true)
>
> object(PDO)#1 (0) { }
>
> SQL: "..."
>
> Result of CALL execurion: bool(true)
>
> SQL: "..."
>
> Result of SELECT execution: bool(true)
>
> Result of fetchAll from SELECT: array(0) {}
>
> Result of Commit: bool(true)
>
> PDO::inTransaction: bool(false)

Like it seems from output - all comes fine and *SELECT* from created global temporarl table just return no data = array(0). Like no data was collected here from stored procedure.

What can be wrong here?

__UPD:

Stored procedure DDL (*I'm really don't understand much in DB2 procedures*):

```
 SET CURRENT SQLID='D90'`                                           

  CREATE PROCEDURE SOME.PROCEDURE

     (IN P0 SMALLINT ,                                               

      IN P1 DATE ,                                                   

      IN P2 INTEGER ,                                                 

      IN P3 INTEGER ,                                                

      IN P4 INTEGER ,                                                

      OUT P5 INTEGER ,                                               

      OUT P6 INTEGER ,                                               

      OUT P7 VARCHAR(800) FOR SBCS DATA CCSID EBCDIC )               

    EXTERNAL NAME 'PROCEDURE'                                         

    LANGUAGE C  PARAMETER STYLE DB2SQL  NOT DETERMINISTIC  FENCED    

    CALLED ON NULL INPUT  MODIFIES SQL DATA  NO PACKAGE PATH         

    NO DBINFO  COLLID LGDP13  WLM ENVIRONMENT DB2DAPP1               

    ASUTIME NO LIMIT  STAY RESIDENT NO  PROGRAM TYPE MAIN            

    SECURITY DEFINER  INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS                      

    STOP AFTER SYSTEM DEFAULT FAILURES  COMMIT ON RETURN NO `
```

**__UPDATED_PROBLEM SOLVED**

dbAdministrator get permissions to access to this db2 fully to all tables.  The was just no data in tthis year =|

Comment: No exception is raised? That's strange. It should be "Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active" and resolved by advancing to the [next resultset](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#call).

Comment: Is the procedure defined with 'COMMIT ON RETURN YES' or is the procedure AUTONOMOUS ?    How have your proved that the sproc inserted rows into the target-table?   Are you sure that the table is a temporal table, or do you mean a declared global temporary table and if you are unsure then show its DDL.

Comment: @mao, hello) updated questiond with stored procedure DDL. (but I don't understand much at this, sorry)
But  it definately says that **COMMIT ON RETURN NO**

Comment: Can you answer the other two questions that I asked?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, No exception. Stored procedures return NO cursor. So no results set from stored procedure. It only collect data and store it in temporal table which I select nothing. (At least it says that it must work in that logic =|)

Comment: @mao,
1) **COMMIT ON RETURN NO**

2) I cannot prove that stored procedure store any information in temporal table. Cause it cleared on commit (end transaction) and if I don't commit - this table will be locked - and no one else (except my code) can't saw what information stores here. 

3) It's *GLOBAL TEMPORARY*

Comment: @mao, **CREATED GLOBAL TEMPORARY**, not *DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY*, if it matters

Comment: OK you should edit the question to replace the phrase "temporal table" by "created global temporary" table (CGTT) because they are quite different things.  If a COMMIT or ROLLBACK has happened the CGTT will get emptied.  VERIFY that the schema of the CGTT that you are using is actually the one used by the sproc.  If that is verified, and you still get no data, then I would (temporarily) eliminate PHP(and PDO) by calling the sproc from a CLP script with autocommit disabled and then select from the CGTT. If that yields no data then commit/rollback happened server side or CGTT was never filled.

Comment: @mao, sproc and CGTT in different schemas. Is it wrong? dbAdministrator says, that everyone else work fine with this sprocs =\

Comment: The schema of the CGTT must match the explicit (or implicit) schema in your SELECT, and there has to be no commit/rollback/release.

Comment: @mao, the schema of CGTT match dchema in SELECT. sproc in different scheme.
Problem solves. dbAdministrator get permissions to access to this db2 fully to all tables.  The was just no data in tthis year =|
Thank you for helping and knowledge, again)